# add custom array to google autocomplete places angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, google-places-api

In my application, I am using autocomplete for google places using the directive  gm-places-autocomplete. I want this autocomplete suggestion to be enhanced with my custom array which has be listed below with existing autocomplete functionality. 
The below shown is my HTML

```
  <input type="text" gm-places-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" class="form-control" id="autoCompleteText" />
```

I have a custom array with details below.

```
      var arrayPlaces={[name:"myHome", lat:25.56,lng:56.12],[name:"office",lat:25.36,lng:51.25]}
```

I want to include this custom array to my autocomplete suggestions. Is there any possible way to implement this.

Other than angular JS, is there any other way using Javascript or Jquery.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I have trouble understanding what you are actually trying to do. I advise you read through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it will help you to improve your question, so it is more likely for you to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

here is a javascript way for your situation. The auto-complete result are editable in callback of `AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions`. After you have got auto-complete result, you can add your own result before showing them.

```js
function initService() {
  var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }

    // add your custom suggestion here
    // add to end
    predictions.push({description: 'custom suggestion 2'});
    // add to head
    predictions.unshift({description: 'custome suggestion 1'});

    predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
      //console.log(prediction);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description));
      document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
    });
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({
    input: 'pizza near Syd'
  }, displaySuggestions);
}
```

```html
<div id="right-panel">
  <p>Query suggestions for 'pizza near Syd':</p>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initService" async defer></script>
```